# How to give different priorities to erlang messages

Tags: erlang

In the book "erlang programming" and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699498/is-there-a-clever-way-to-give-messages-different-priorities) stack overflow question I have seen that we can give different priorities to erlang messages in the mailbox using:

I tried to implement something similar with this code:

```
-module(mytest).
-export([start/0, test/0]).

start() ->
    register(?MODULE, spawn(fun() -> do_receive() end)).

do_receive() ->
    receive
        {high_p, Message} ->
            io:format("High priority: ~p~n", [Message]),
            do_receive()
    after 0 ->
            receive
                {low_p, Message} ->
                    io:format("Low priority: ~p~n", [Message]),
                    do_receive()
            end
    end.

test() ->
    mytest ! {high_p, msg1},
    mytest ! {low_p, msg2},
    mytest ! {high_p, msg3}.
```

But the result was:

```
1> mytest:start().
true
2> mytest:test(). 
Low priority: msg2
{high_p,msg3}
High priority: msg1
High priority: msg3
```

Which seems not right, so I changed the code as:

```
do_receive() ->
    receive
        {high_p, Message} ->
            io:format("High priority: ~p~n", [Message]),
            do_receive()
    after 0 ->
            receive
                {high_p, _} = Other ->
                    self() ! Other,
                    do_receive();
                {low_p, Message} ->
                    io:format("Low priority: ~p~n", [Message]),
                    do_receive()
            end
    end.
```

and the result is the following (all high priority messages are printed before the low priority ones).

```
1> mytest:start().
true
2> mytest:test(). 
High priority: msg3
{high_p,msg3}
High priority: msg1
Low priority: msg2
```

Is this the correct way in order to achieve my goal? And can different priorities be achieved within gen_server handle_info/2 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what happens in the first program is:

1. you spawn the receiver at the "receive high-priority message" state
2. he finds no high-priority message so he goes to "receive low-priority message" state
3. you send a high priority message but it's not recognised
4. you send a low priority message and it is recognised
5. then the receiver loops and goes to the "high priority message" state and recognises the messages

so there could even be a deadlock where the receiver would have a ton of high-priority messages but cannot process them cause he's stuck in the low-priority state

therefore, I think that your approach (which is similar to the answer to the question you linked) is better.
an optimisation: since you receive a high-priority message there is no need to send it again (and cause additional overhead):

```
do_receive() ->
    receive
        {high_p, Message} ->
            do_high(Message)
    after 0 ->
            receive
                {high_p, Message} ->
                    do_high(Message);
                {low_p, Message} ->
                    io:format("Low priority: ~p~n", [Message])
            end
    end,
    do_receive().

do_high(Message) ->
    io:format("High priority: ~p~n", [Message]).
```

Comment: by the way can i achieve priorities in handle_info ?

Comment: @user601836 i'm not really sure about that, sorry

Comment: @user601836 You mean in a gen_server or gen_fsm? No, you can't, not easily like here anyway. The message receiving is done for you in the gen_server loop so `handle_info`, and `handle_call` and `handle_cast`, are called in the order the messages arrive. You could explicitly check for a high-priority message inside the `handle_info` as above but that wouldn't occur until something else occurs. This is one of the downsides of using gen_servers, you lose explicit control of receiving messages.

Comment: thank you for pointing out this, i will stick to my own custom process then, using proc_lib:start_link to start it